# How to remove document["oncontextmenu"] and document["onselectstart"]?

Tags: javascript

Say if someone set the following on a webpage:

```
document.oncontextmenu = function(){return false;};
document.onselectstart = function(){return false;};
```

How would I be able to remove them using injected javascript?

`removeEventListener` doesn't seem to work because there is no event name.

Comment: Maybe `document.oncontextmenu = null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the listener has indeed been set via assignment to an `on-` property, then it's as simple as reassigning that property:

```
document.oncontextmenu = null;
document.onselectstart = null;
```

But those listeners are often added via `addEventListener` rather than via an `on-` assignment. In that case, you might monkeypatch `addEventListener` *before* the page loads to have it only attach listeners you want to permit to attach. For example:

```js
const nativeListener = document.addEventListener;
document.addEventListener = (...args) => {
  const type = args[0];
  if (type === 'selectstart' || type === 'contextmenu') return;
  nativeListener.apply(document, args);
}

// left click listener works normally
document.addEventListener('click', () => console.log('click'));

// right click listener is never attached:
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', () => console.log('contextmenu'));
```

```html
<div>content</div>
```

If you want to use this in a userscript, make sure to use

```
// @run-at    document-start
```

so that the monkeypatching occurs *before* the document's ordinary scripts run (and attempt to attach listeners).